# "Elle a réussi 3 fois plus que moi" ou "elle a réussi 3 fois de plus que moi"?

Tags: expressions, usage, choix-de-mot, mathématiques, comparaison-de-langues

Bonjour,

Quel est la différence entre les deux phrases suivantes :

> *Elle a réussi 3 fois plus que moi.*
> *Elle a réussi 3 fois de plus que moi.*

Dans le paragraphe suivant, le sens change-t-il si j'enlève ou ajoute le "de"?

*Nous avons marqué plusieurs points chacun. J'en ai réussi 7, le meilleur record du moment, mais grâce à son poids et sa rapidité, elle a réussi trois fois (**de**) plus que moi.*

Est-ce que sans le "de" on comprendra qu'elle a réussi 3*7=21 fois?
Et qu'avec, qu'elle en a réussi 3+7=10?

Comment: De quel sport s'agit-il ?

Comment: «3 fois plus de points que moi». Aucune des 2 propositions n’est correcte.

Comment: @PtitXav hors contexte, les deux me paraissent tout à fait correctes. "Réussi trois fois plus que moi" semble juste incongru après une première proposition où on parle de nombre de points, mais ce n'est pas faux. "Trois fois *de* plus" peut simplement vouloir dire qu'elle a réussi 3 tentatives de plus (chaque tentative rapportant des points).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oui, sans le 'de' on comprendrait trois fois plus dans le sens (mon nombre de fois) x 3 alors que 'trois fois de plus que moi' serait  (mon nombre de fois) + 3.
À noter que ces deux formulations me semblent assez familières ou du langage parlé.

Answer (score 1):

La première phrase n'est pas très naturelle, la deuxième n'est pas très grammaticale.

Voici comment je réécrirais le paragraphe :

*Nous avons toutes les deux marqué des points. J'en ai réussi sept, le record à ce moment là, mais grâce à son poids et sa rapidité, **elle en a finalement marqué trois fois plus que moi**.*

---

1. *Est-ce que sans le "de" on comprendra qu'elle a réussi 3x7=21 fois?*

   Si la personne qui s'exprime maitrise mal le français, on comprendrait qu'elle essaie de dire ça, oui, mais le verbe *réussir* n'est pas le bon ou il manque *en*.

   *Elle a réussi trois fois plus que moi* ❌
   *Elle **en** a réussi trois fois plus que moi.* ✅ (21 points)
   *Elle a **marqué** trois fois plus que moi.* ✅ (21 points)
2. *Et qu'avec, qu'elle en a réussi 3+7=10?*

   Non, on ne comprendrait pas vraiment ce qui est dit, ou alors, avec indulgence, la même chose que précédemment.

   *Elle a réussi trois fois de plus que moi* ❌
   *Elle en a réussi trois fois de plus que moi.* ❌
   *Elle a marqué trois fois de plus que moi.* ❌
   *Elle a marqué trois **points** de plus que moi.* ✅  (10 points)

Comment: Merci pour votre correction mais ça ne répond à ma question...

Comment: La différence est que la première phrase est grammaticalement correcte mais ne correspond pas à la situation décrite alors que la deuxième phrase est incorrecte. De quel sport s'agit-il ?

Comment: Je ne sais pas de quel sport, il s'agit d'une phrase dans mon manuel ...

Comment: Peut-on en savoir plus sur ce manuel ? Nom ? Éditeur ? Année  ? Page ? Tu peux aussi afficher une photo de la page en question.

Comment: Manuel SVT de Jean Michel Gardarain, 4e il me semble, mais je ne me souviens pas de la page.

Comment: Donc, tu cites ces expressions de mémoire ?

Comment: Oui, donc c'est pour ca qu'il y a des imprécisions.

Comment: Je serais curieux de savoir ce qui est vraiment écrit dans ce livre. Si tu remets la main dessus, n'hésites pas à éditer ta question !